# React Boostrap CardDeck does not align horizontally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass, jsx

I am new with React and I am trying to display three cards in a row but they do not align horizontally, they are vertically (from top to bottom). I tried using cardDeck or cardGroup, but they do not work. Below is the code

```
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Style.scss";

const Item = ({ varietals }) => {
    return (
    <>
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={varietals.pictureUrl} />
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{varietals.title}</Card.Title>
                {/* <Card.Text>
                  {varietals.description}
                </Card.Text> */}
                <Button variant="info">Details</Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>        
    </>
    )
};


export default Item;
```

Also, I did a sass file to import in the code above but it seems it does not work. This is the simple code fo the sass file:

```
.clem {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
};
```

In addition, this is the itemList where I do the map of the items:

```
import Item from "../Item/Item";
    
const ItemList = ({ varietals }) => {
  return (
      <div>    
        {varietals.map((varietals) => {
        return <Item key={varietals.id} varietals={varietals} className="row" />;
        })};  
      </div>
  );
};


  export default ItemList;
```

Last, this is the itemListContainer where I did the promise:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ItemList from "../Components/ItemList/ItemList";    

const ItemListContainer = () => {
  
  const [varietals, setVarietals] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(Aimara), 2000);
  });

  myPromise.then((result) => setVarietals(result));
  }, []);
    return (
        <>
          <ItemList varietals={varietals} />
          <ItemCountComponent stock={5} initial={1}/>
        </>
    )
};

export default ItemListContainer;
```

I hope someone could solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the class `.clem` in your ItemList main `div` like blow. So that It will apply the horizontal row style for your Card Container.

```
const ItemList = ({ varietals }) => {
   return (
     <div className="clem">    
        {varietals.map((varietals) => {
          return <Item key={varietals.id} varietals={varietals} className="row" />;
        })};  
     </div>
  );
};
```

Otherwise you can use `Card Group` for your requirement. But `<CardGroup>` should not in the repeated section. It should be placed on common where currently we have applied class `clem`. Refer the details [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-groups)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a "CardGroup" in your ItemList component wrapping "Card" to display them properly. The class "row" won't be necessary

```
import Item from "./Item";
import { CardGroup } from "react-bootstrap";


const ItemList = ({ varietals }) => {
  return (
      <CardGroup>    
        {varietals.map((varietals) => {
        return <Item key={varietals.id} varietals={varietals} />
        })}
      </CardGroup>
  );
};


export default ItemList;
```